# Why is the decomposition of $\operatorname{Tor}(M)$ into cyclic modules a "subset" of the decomposition of $M$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, finitely-generated

In my book it says that if $M$ is finitely generated over $R$, a P.I.D., then

$$M \cong R^r \oplus R/(a_1) \oplus \cdots \oplus R/(a_n)$$

and that

$$\operatorname{Tor}(M) \cong R/(a_1) \oplus \cdots \oplus R/(a_n)$$

I don't understand how the second part follows from the first. First, I don't see why $\operatorname{Tor}(M)$ has to be finitely generated; I know that a submodule of a finitely generated module is not necessarily finitely generated.

Secondly, if we assume that $\operatorname{Tor}(M)$ is finitely generated, then we can apply the theorem and get

$$\operatorname{Tor}(M) \cong R^k \oplus R/(b_1) \oplus \cdots \oplus R/(b_m)$$

I understand that since it's a torsion module, $k$ should equal zero. But I don't see why the $R/(b_1) \oplus \cdots \oplus R/(b_m)$ part has to be the same as the $R/(a_1) \oplus \cdots \oplus R/(a_n)$ part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of thinking of Tor$(M)$, just think of Tor$(R^k \oplus R/(b_1) \oplus \cdots \oplus R/(b_m))$. It is clear that this is just $R/(b_1) \oplus \cdots \oplus R/(b_m)$, and therefore so is the torsion submodule of $M$.

Answer (score 1):

1. A P.I.D. is a noetherian ring, and a finitely generated module over a noetherian ring is noetherian, i.e. all its submodules are finitely generated.
2. There is a uniqueness part in the *Structure theorem for finitely generated modules over a P.I.D.*

Comment: Ok got the first part; but what I said in my question is part of the existence theorem, which is given before the uniqueness theorem. Even so, let's assume uniqueness. To get that $\operatorname{Tor}(M) \cong R/(a_1) \oplus \cdots \oplus R/(a_2)$, wouldn't we have to show that $M \cong R^r \oplus \operatorname{Tor}(M)$ also?

Comment: But this is the case: a finitely generated  module over a  P.I.D. (or more generally, a Dedekind ring) is the direct sum of its torsion submodule $T$ and a projective module (projective modules are free in the case of P.I.D.s) simply because we hace a surjective homomorphism $M\to R^k$ with kernel $T$.